# java swing: modify rectangle without creating a new one

Tags: java, swing, intersection

I’m using swing and I’m having a problem. I’m making capture the flag, and when the blue team gets hit by a red player on the red side the blue player should reset on their own side. My problem is that the blue player respawns on their own side but doesn’t disappear from the red side, so I end up with two blue squares. I think this is because I’m resetting the blue player by doing

```
bluePlayer=new Rectangle(coords)
```

so I'm creating a new rectangle while leaving the old one. I've tried modifying the syntax, like for example

```
bluePlayer=(coords);
```

or

```
bluePlayer=Rectangle(coords);
```

but both give me errors. I think this is similar to changing the value of, for example, int 'example' after declaring it, like so:

```
int example=10;
example=5;
```

But for me, rather than the value of example changing, it's creating a second integer, also called example. I should add that when I move the blue square using the arrow keys, I can move the blue square that's touching the red square, and when I move the blue square away from the red square (they're no longer touching), the second blue square goes away.

Here is my code for resetting the blue square:

```
if(bluePlayer.intersects(leftSide) && redPlayer.intersects(bluePlayer)){
    bluePlayer=new Rectangle(1100, 300, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(bluePlayer.x, bluePlayer.y, bluePlayer.width, bluePlayer.height);
}
```

Here are some screenshots that should help explain my problem:

The blue square and red square are on opposite sides and are not touching, there is no problem here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtmVJ.png

The blue square is on the red square's side and is touching the red square, and there is another blue square on the blue square's side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/780ZZ.png

Here is my code inside of the paintComponent method. Note that what I referred to as bluePlayer above is actually named player2 in the code. I know my code is messy, I still need to clean it up.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Rectangle leftSide=new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 700);
    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.fillRect(leftSide.x, leftSide.y, leftSide.width, leftSide.height);
    Rectangle rightSide=new Rectangle(600, 0, 600, 700);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(rightSide.x, rightSide.y, rightSide.width, rightSide.height);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    Rectangle player1=new Rectangle(player1X, player1Y, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.width, player1.height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Rectangle player2=new Rectangle(player2X, player2Y, 50, 50);
    g.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);

    Rectangle redFlag=new Rectangle(150, 313, 25, 25);

    if(blueHasRedFlag==false){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(redFlag.x, redFlag.y, redFlag.width, redFlag.height);
    }

    if(player2.intersects(redFlag)){
        blueHasRedFlag=true;
        player1=new Rectangle(player1X, player1Y, 75, 75);
    }

    if(player2.intersects(leftSide) && player1.intersects(player2)){
        player2=new Rectangle(1100, 300, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);
    }

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Creating a new instance of `Rectangle` should reset `bluePlayer`, assuming it's the correct reference. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added a code snippet above, sorry. I added Rectangle, like so:

Rectangle bluePlayer=new Rectangle(1100, 300, 50, 50);

And I got the error: "Duplicate local variable bluePlayer". Am I doing this incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: No, I would say not, but without more context is difficult to know exactly what the problem is and how you might fix it

Comment: I created a rectangle initially: `Rectangle bluePlayer=new Rectangle(bluePlayerX, bluePlayerY, 50, 50);` then, `g.fillRect(bluePlayer.x, bluePlayer.y, bluePlayer.width, bluePlayer.height);`, then I modified it using the code snippet in the original question above.

Comment: It seems what you are painting and what you're modifying are two different things, but that's all guess work without a runnable example to verify with

Comment: What can you use to run java swing online? Or do you just want me to paste my code into a pastebin?

Comment: Update the answer with the code example. We'll either read it or download it and run it ourselves

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define and paint `player2`...

```
Rectangle player2=new Rectangle(player2X, player2Y, 50, 50);
g.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);
```

You then test `player2`'s position and paint `player2`s new position...again...

```
if(player2.intersects(leftSide) && player1.intersects(player2)){
    player2=new Rectangle(1100, 300, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);
}
```

Remember, painting is like painting on to a canvas, it's accumulative.

Generally speaking, painting is for painting and shouldn't contain any logic within that isn't related to painting the current state.

Assuming you have some kind of update loop or cycle, you should be calculating the logic within it and simply painting the state.  These two operations should be done separately...

Comment: Ah, alright, I see. So I removed the first g.fillRect you pointed out, and changed the if to just set player2X to 1100, and player2Y to 300. Then, before repaint();, I added `g.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height);` I think I understand what you said about the loop; I don't have one yet, but I think I will create one in the future. Thanks for your help!